# java.io.FileNotFoundException in android URLConnection

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am facing the following exception when i try to call method on server, can any one tell me what is the problem ?

**stacktrace**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://services.q84sale.com/live/index.php/V1/Users/register
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
com.forsale.forsale.controller.manager.ForSaleNetworkManager.execute(ForSaleNetworkManager.java:116)
com.forsale.forsale.controller.manager.ForSaleServerManager$18.doInBackground(ForSaleServerManager.java:1423)
com.forsale.forsale.controller.manager.ForSaleServerManager$18.doInBackground(ForSaleServerManager.java:1399)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:848)
```

Comment: You are tring to access a web server file as if it was a file located on your file system. Which is **wrong by definition**. This is what you are presented with, if you try opening that path in FireFox: `{"status":400,"error":{"code":1,"message_en":"Invalid HTTP Method. Only POST is Accepted.","message_ar":"Invalid HTTP Method. Only POST is Accepted."}}`. It seems you need a tutorial on **webservices**.

Answer (score 1):

Too little information for right answer. Probably:

1. You specified an object with in your query that doesn't exist on server
2. You are using wrong method (GET, PUT) instead of POST
3. Server has some errors in its code

Add:

I noticed you are using `.getInputStream()` after receiving response code above 399. Check `.getResponseCode()` and then use `.getErrorStream()` instead

Comment: Server return error code 422 with JSON object contains error message when I test the request on postman.

Comment: Returning a java.io.FileNotFoundException is just a very bad design decision. There are man 4xx HTTP codes which have nothing to do with files. In our case it was HTTP 420.